# Refresh div after form submit not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '.error_box_wrapper',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse,  // post-submit callback 
    }; 
    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#edit_group_form').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 
// pre-submit callback 
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    return true; 
}  
// post-submit callback 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {  
    alert("Success!");
} 
</script>
```

I'm using the Jquery form plugin, after the form is submitted, I would like a div on page to refresh.

Comment: You have no code in here that will update any div.  showResponse only performs an alert.

Comment: is anything happening? Are you getting the alert?

Comment: yes I get an alert, Not sure where to place the refresh div code, I've tried placing before the alert with no success.

Comment: this is the pice of code I was using:<br>

$('#middle').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #middle' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the HTML in your div with ID 'myDiv':

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {  
    alert("Success!");
    $('#myDiv').html('YAY!');
}
```

**EDIT**

In order to clarify my response based on comments, you should do something like this to refresh the data in the div:

```
var $newData = $(document.createElement('div'))
.append(
    $(document.createElement('div'))
        .append("First Name: "+results.User.first_name)
)
.append(
    $(document.createElement('div'))
        .append("Last Name: "+results.User.last_name)
);

$('#DivName').html($newData);
```

This creates a new HTML element with data based on a fake results object.  You will have to tweak your code based on how you return data from your ajax call, but this should give you an idea of how to update the data without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: That Just populate my div with "YAY!", I want to refresh mydiv with new content.

Comment: Yay is new content. Change 'Yay!' to the content that you want to provide when it is done.  You can add any HTML string, most jQuery objects, or javascript variable string.

Comment: I guess you need to clarify what you mean by "refresh with new content."

Comment: Just refresh the div. After form submission I would like to refresh a DIV.

Comment: Refresh it with what? You haven't stated what you want to put in there? Changing the html as listed is "refreshing" the div as far as taking out the old content and putting something new. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry man, not trying to be a pain, I have several divs on the same page as my form,, when the user fills out the form, then clicks on submit, I want a div refreshed. The div is already populated with data from mysql, I just want it refreshed after the from is submitted.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a div with some data that is related to the form, but it's already populated.  Is this data being updated with the data that is in the form?  If so, you can't just "refresh" a div without reloading the page. You either need to construct HTML that will replace the old HTML in that div with new  /updated HTML or refresh the whole page. You should rewrite your question to state this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a newb, Uhm..ok so I can't refresh a div without reloading the page..hrm..ok..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
target:        '.error_box_wrapper',
```

try with id instead of class:

```
target:        '#error_box_wrapper',
```

Comment: This part works fine, it's on success that I want a div refreshed.

Comment: So your have new content in your div after submit?

Answer (score 0):

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {  
    alert("Success!");
    $('#divID').innerHTML('new content');
}
```